# BitPay.RequestInvoiceWebhookToBeResent fails

Tags: c#, bitpay-c#-sdk

When I try to call this method, I get the following exception: {"There is no token for the specified key"}.  The call to retrieve the invoice is successful, but fails on the call to RequestInvoideWebhookToBeResent.  I am using a Merchant POSkey
I have removed the call to retrieve the invoice, to see if that was impacting the call, but the call failed with the same response.

```
 public BitPay.Client bitPay
    {
        get
        {
            if (bp == null)
            {
                PosToken token = new PosToken(BitPayToken);
                BitPay.Environment bpEnviro = BitPayEnvironment.Equals("Test") ? BitPay.Environment.Test : BitPay.Environment.Prod;

                bp = new BitPay.Client(token, bpEnviro);
            }
            return bp;  
        }
    }
public Invoice RequestResend(string invoiceId)
    {
        bool result = false;
        Invoice invoice = RetrieveInvoice(invoiceId);
        try
        {

            result = bitPay.RequestInvoiceWebhookToBeResent(invoiceId).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("BitPay RequestInvoiceWebhookToBeResent: {0} Invoice Id:{1}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex.InnerException.Message) ? ex.Message: ex.InnerException.Message, invoiceId));
        }
        return invoice;
    }
```